# Is there a way to replace third similar char by *?

Tags: sql, oracle

If a string lets say 'abcafgadf' is taken. So I want to replace the third 'a' by '*'. How should I write the query.

I'm trying to solve it on Oracel SQL
With instr,substr and replace function.
Please help.

Comment: Please show is what you've tried so far and explain why it's not working.

Comment: are you familiar with `regexp_Replace`?https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. **Show us the actual code that you've tried**, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 2):

> ... With instr,substr and replace function.

Actually, you don't even need `replace` (see lines #3 and 4). Regular expressions make it *prettier* (line #6):

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'abcafgadf' from dual)
  3  select substr(col, 1, instr(col, 'a', 1, 3) - 1) || '*' ||
  4         substr(col, instr(col, 'a', 1, 3) + 1) as result,
  5         --
  6         regexp_replace(col, 'a', '*', 1, 3) as result_2
  7  from test;

RESULT    RESULT_2
--------- ---------
abcafg*df abcafg*df

SQL>
```